# Beautiful soup finding tags within tags

Tags: python, html, unit-testing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a unittest where one can find body tags within html tag, I've attempted to make the following test but I'm seeing a syntax error for some reason, I have properly set up Beautiful Soup, etc:

```
for tag in soup.find_all(re.compile("""<html.*><body.*></body></html>""")):
    count+=1
self.assertEqual(count,1)
```

Comment: Why do it like this? Why not just search for all `html` tags, then check if there's a `body` tag inside each `html` tag?

Comment: Well the test I want to make is specifically to find that body tags are inside the html tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.parent` attribute to see what the parent tag of the tag of interest is:

```
html = '<html>\
 <head>\
  <title>Test</title>\
 </head>\
 <body>\
  bla\
<a><body></body></a>\
 </body>\
</html>\
<body>\
 bla\
</body>'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
bodies = soup.findAll('body')
for body in bodies:
  parent = body.parent.name
  if ( parent == 'html' ):
    print('Good! Parent = ' + body.parent.name)
  else:
    print('Uh oh! Parent = ' + body.parent.name)
```

The sample document contains a `<body>` tag that's properly the child of an `<html>` tag, one that's nested within other tags, and one that is outside the document altogether. The output is this:

```
Good! Parent = html
Uh oh! Parent = a
Uh oh! Parent = [document]
```